# Tool tip for Stacked Bar Chart using MarkerView & Issues in Legends

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I want to Display a Stacked Bar Chart in my Android Application with tooltip functionality. I used the MarkerView to display it but no Success. Here is the sample code.

Also I am facing issues in Legends..!
As text wrapping is not supported by the Library the legends are not showing.
And the values at Y-axis are showing in Integer. which I want to display in Floats. Can I give '%' in Y-axis values? Something like this,

https://drive.google.com/a/findabilitysciences.com/file/d/0B-kRufrwei7wSHFMQjVDMkdTNVk/view?usp=sharing

```
        chart1 = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart1);
                    chart1.setDrawYValues(true);
                    //chart1.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);
                    chart1.setDescription("");
                    chart1.set3DEnabled(false);
                    chart1.setUnit("%");
                    chart1.setDrawGridBackground(false);
                    chart1.setDrawHorizontalGrid(true);
                    chart1.setValueTextSize(8f);
                    chart1.setDrawBorder(false);
                    chart1.setYRange(0.0f,100.0f,true);
                    chart1.setDrawLegend(true);
                    chart1.setPinchZoom(true);
                    chart1.setTouchEnabled(true);
                    //Code for Tooltip at barchart.
                    /*MyMarkerView mv = new MyMarkerView(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.custom_marker_view);
                    mv.setOffsets(-mv.getMeasuredWidth() / 2, -mv.getMeasuredHeight());
                    chart1.setMarkerView(mv);*/






                    XLabels xl = chart1.getXLabels();
                    xl.setPosition(XLabels.XLabelPosition.BOTTOM);
                    xl.setSpaceBetweenLabels(10);
                    xl.setCenterXLabelText(true);

                    YLabels yl = chart1.getYLabels();
                    //yl.setLabelCount(10);
                    yl.setPosition(YLabels.YLabelPosition.LEFT);


                    setData();

                    Legend l = chart1.getLegend();
                    l.setPosition(Legend.LegendPosition.BELOW_CHART_RIGHT);
                    l.setFormSize(8f);
                    l.setYEntrySpace(4f);

                    chart1.animateY(3000);


                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Occurred [Server's JSON response might be invalid]!" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

        private void setData() {
            ArrayList<String> xVals = new <String>ArrayList<String>();
            xVals.add("Donors");
            xVals.add("Amount");

            ArrayList<BarEntry> yVals1 = new <BarEntry>ArrayList<BarEntry>();

            yVals1.add(new BarEntry(new float[]{donoravg.get(0),donoravg.get(1),donoravg.get(2),donoravg.get(3),donoravg.get(4),donoravg.get(5),donoravg.get(6),donoravg.get(7),donoravg.get(8),donoravg.get(9),donoravg.get(10)}, 0));
            yVals1.add(new BarEntry(new float[]{amountavg.get(0),amountavg.get(1),amountavg.get(2),amountavg.get(3),amountavg.get(4),amountavg.get(5),amountavg.get(6),amountavg.get(7),amountavg.get(8),amountavg.get(9)}, 1));

            BarDataSet set1 = new BarDataSet(yVals1, "");
            set1.setStackLabels(new String[]{"All other defector count", "Last Year Defector Count", "At Risk Donor Count"});
            set1.setBarSpacePercent(40f);
            set1.setColors(new int[]{R.color.pink_400, R.color.purple_300, R.color.deep_purple_300, R.color.indigo_300, R.color.cyan_300, R.color.teal_300, R.color.amber_300, R.color.deep_orange_300, R.color.brown_300, R.color.blue_grey_300}, getApplicationContext());

            ArrayList<BarDataSet> dataSets = new <BarDataSet>ArrayList<BarDataSet>();
            dataSets.add(set1);
            BarData data = new BarData(xVals, dataSets);
            chart1.setData(data);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new library of mpAndroidChart v2.0.7 resolved all the issues.
using .setValueFormatter(); we can format Y axis value as well as chart values.

For Legend problem, 
Instead of showing Legends I added Touch Listener which can work on stack values.
The touch listener can show the details of value.